# Cannot get MOXy (JAXB) to work in my application

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

I tried to use MOXy's ObjectGraph feature to marshal a subset of class fields to a xml string. I have done the followings:

1. Put the `eclipselink.jar` in the classpath
2. Created a `jaxb.properties` file, have the content to be  `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory`, and put it in the same package as my domain class that I want to marshal or unmarshal.

I wrote a method in the domain class, which marshals the subset of fields to a xml string. I called this method in the classes `main()` method, and I got the correct result.

My application is in an `ear` file, and the domain classes are packaged in a `model.jar` file. The marshalling method is called by a service class which is in the same jar file. After I deployed to WebLogic server and ran the function which uses this marshalling function, I always got the exception at the line:

```
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.OBJECT_GRAPH, "dbstring");
```

Basically I cannot set this `OBJECT_GRAPH` property, and cannot get the correct marshalling result. However if I ran the domain class in the `model.jar`, it was fine.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What exception do you get?

Answer (score 0):

We introduced the Object Graph feature in EclipseLink 2.5.0 (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Object%20Graphs). EclipseLink MOXy is the default JAXB provider in WebLogic (as of 12.1.1, see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/eclipselink-moxy-is-jaxb-provider-in.html) but as of today (Nov 7, 2013) this version of EclipseLink has not been included in a release version of WebLogic.  The following article will help you use a newer version of EclipseLink in WebLogic.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/10/updating-eclipselink-in-weblogic.html